# How to get host where problem appears Zabbix-api

Tags: python, zabbix, zabbix-api

I'm trying to make a script on Python, which works with zabbix-api.

For example: Trigger worked, problem appears and then I make an "action trigger", which will work on that host, where problem appeared. For the script, I need to get host (and host id), where problem appeared and then resolve the problem. But I don't know how to get only this host.
Please, could you help me with this or maybe give me some advice, what am I doing wrong?

I tried something like:

```
my_host = zabbix_log.host.get(limit=1, output=["hostid", "name", "host"])[0]
```

Of course, it works, but I understand, that this is only give to me some random host, and not the host where problem appeared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used command line arguments (macros) for resolving my issue. The point was to get hostname and hostid where problem appears.

So inside "script window" in global scripts I wrote something like:

```
python script.py {HOSTNAME} {HOST.ID}
```

And in the `script.py`:

```
import sys

hostname = sys.argv[1]
hostid = sys.argv[2]
```

Supported macros:

- https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/6.2/en/manual/appendix/macros/supported_by_location

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1**: how to find all hosts with problems?

Use the `problem.get` method. You can then filter by `$.name` the resulting JSON, if needed.

See:
https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/api/reference/problem/get

**Question 2**: how to close a problem?

Use the `event.acknowledge` method.

See:

- https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/api/reference/event/acknowledge
- https://blog.zabbix.com/close-problem-automatically-via-zabbix-api/12461/